# How to put button in a pressed state when an activity starts?

Tags: java, android

In one of my [activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), how can I make sure that a set of buttons are already activated (clicked/pressed state), when the activity starts?

If possible, please suggest in both layout as well as [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) code.

Answer (score 3):

In your `onCreate` after button initialization you can do

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(this); // activity implements onClickListener interface
button.performClick();
```

if that is what you mean by activated and button meaning normal `Button`.

If you require to change the background or color of button when pressed you can use a selector

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check a checkbox/radiobutton or any `Checkable`, just call

```
view.setChecked(true);
```

If you need to make the view background drawable selector choose the `pressed` state,

```
view.setState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed });
```